# Convert DateTime Format using Convert function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Can anyone help me to find out below format using `Convert` function in SQL Server?

DateTime

```
yyyy/MM/dd hhmm
yyyy/MM/dd hhmmssstt
```

Time

```
hh:mm
hh:mm:ss tt
hh:mm tt
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The full list of date and time styles inbuilt is on the page *[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)*. Anything else will require code.**But** it would be far better to do such formatting on the client if possible (because then you can format as per the user's locale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to get exact format which i need with Convert() so i am using Format() now.

Also want to say Format() is poor performance compare to Convert().

Answer (score 2):

[This MSDN page here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) lists all available "styles" for conversion.

If you're using SQL Server **2012** or newer, you can also look [at the new `FORMAT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) for even more flexibility

Comment: However, as Aaron Bertrand points out http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but `FORMAT()` is a little slower than conventional methods.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson: that's quite possible - but it's also a lot more flexible - pick what is most appropriate for your case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SQL provides different methods to convert date and time.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these statements:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 121), 1, 16), ':', ''), '-', '/')
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 121), ':', ''), '-', '/'), '.', '')
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 114), 1, 5)
SELECT STUFF(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 114), 1, 11), 9, 1, ' ')
SELECT STUFF(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 114), 1, 11), 6, 4, ' ')
```

for these results:

```
2015/07/13 1357
2015/07/13 135723767
13:57
13:57:23 76
13:57 76
```